# jquery clone only text not the attributes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on jquery clone. Where I have a div and three elements. First element was select drop down and second was text box and the third was add button. When the user click the add button it was cloning the entire div perfectly. But if the user select from the dropdown value as other the closest textbox needs be enabled this was working fine for the first time. If the user click the add button the text box should be in disabled mode because the user has not select the other from the drop down field.

Here is my jquery code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn_add").click(function() {
    $("#duplicate").clone(true).insertAfter("#duplicate");
  });
  $("#txt_select").change(function() {
    if ($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "Other") {
      $("#sel_ipt").find("#sel_ipt").removeAttr("disabled").val('');
    } else {
      $("#sel_ipt").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="duplicate">
  <select id="txt_select">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="First">First</option>
    <option value="Second">Second</option>
    <option value="Third">Third</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" disabled id="sel_ipt" />
  <input type="submit" id="btn_add" value="Add" />
</div>
```

Kindly please guide me

Here is my JSBIN [Link](http://jsbin.com/tovutu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: When I selected the dropdown value as other, the closest textbox did not get enabled. Can you verify and let me know the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID's should always be unique in the DOM. When you clone now, you have several #sel_ipt (amongst others) which isn't correct. If you are going to do a form post with these, you should probably keep track of how many inputs you have, and add a number to the copy. Like id="sel_ipt_2" name="sel_ipt_2".

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".txt_select").on('change',function () {

   // Find the input in the specific row
   var input = $(this).parent().find('.sel_ipt');

   input.attr("disabled", $(this).val() != "Other").val('');

  /* 
  This is (probably) better for readability

  if ($(this).val() == "Other") {
     input.attr("disabled", $(this).val() == "Other").val('');
   } else {
     input.attr("disabled", true).val('');
   }*/

 }); 

 $("#btn_add").click(function(){

   // Get the parent row for cloning
   var row = $(this).parent();

   // Insert the row after the cloned row
   var clonedRow = row.clone(true).insertAfter(row);

   // Disable and remove value in the cloned row
   clonedRow.find('.sel_ipt').attr('disabled', true).val('');

 }); 
});
```

Here is a [JS-bin link](http://jsbin.com/noxevipima/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 6):

First, since you are duplicating, don't use `id`, rather use `class`.

I changed your function and added comments to make you understand how the function works.

```js
$( function(){
  $(".btn_add").click(function(){
    // clone the first .duplicate
    var clone = $(".duplicate:first").clone(true);
    // find the text input, change the disabled property and empty the value
    clone.find(".sel_ipt").attr("disabled","disabled").val('');
    // insert after the last .dublicate
    clone.insertAfter(".duplicate:last");
  });
  $(".txt_select").change(function () {
    if ($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "Other") {
      // use next to find the next element with class .sel_ipt
      $(this).next(".sel_ipt").removeAttr("disabled").val('');
    } else {
      $(this).next(".sel_ipt").attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="duplicate">
  <select class="txt_select">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="First">First</option>
    <option value="Second">Second</option>
    <option value="Third">Third</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" disabled class="sel_ipt" />
  <input type="submit" class="btn_add" value="Add" />
</div>
```

Comment: Classes all day long. However, and since you are iterating over an unknown amount of clones, you could probably tap into the :eq(0) index selection method and put it into a function that dynamically increments.
`function(i)` `class='eq(' + i + ')'` + `lastdupe`

That was sloppily written but I only wanted to convey the idea.